# Wicket Drop down choice to set default value

Tags: wicket

I want to replace "choose one" option in drop down choice with other String "successfully occured" and I dont want to show list item to set the default.

```
DropDownChoice<Person> customer = new DropDownChoice<Person>(
                        "customer", new PropertyModel<Person>(customermodel, "customer"),list, new ChoiceRenderer<Person>("name", "id"));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to do this is to put the definition

```
customer.null=successfully occured
```

in a properties file associated with the form or page containing the choice.

The properties file can also be localized so that what's shown depends on the locale.

Comment: +1 But don't forget about the `customer.nullValid` resource key when using `setNullValid(true)`, which might be the one the OP is using ("successfully occured" seems like a valid null value)

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to do following to get this done.

```
customer.setNullValid(true);
```

Then created a file named "HomePage.properties" (I added the drop down to HomePage)

set the null text in the .properties file as bellow.

```
nullValid=Choose one..
```